# Send form data with requests in Python not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm start learning python with requests library and i get facebook for example.

This is my code:

```
import requests
get_response = requests.get(url='https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?
ctx=recover')
post_data = {'email':'mycorrectemailaddress'}
post_response = requests.post(url="https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover/POST", data=post_data)
print(post_response.text)
```

And my script not going to the next page, i don't know where is my fault.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @stamaimer
No error
After send POST data script will show me my profil, but all time print me start page...

Comment: @Andersson

Maybe you? :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass all the required data.

```
payload = {lsd:AVpg3ZvY
           email:your@email.com
           did_submit:Search
           __user:0
           __a:1
           __dyn:7AzHK4GgN1t2u6XgmwCwRAKGzEy4S-C11xG12wAxu13wIwHx27QdwPG2iuUG4XzEa8uwh9UcU88lwIwHwJwnoCcxG48hwv9FovgeFUuzUhws82BxCqUkguy99UK
           __af:iw
           __req:5
           __be:-1
           __pc:PHASED:DEFAULT
           __rev:2929740}
```

Sadly, I don't know what are these args. But you could parse it from a get requrest on the page or use selenium for the informations, and pass cookies to the requests module, and then make the post request.

Comment: Pls look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167530/send-post-data-in-input-form-and-scrap-page-python-requests-library

Comment: I checked, you still don't send all the required parameter. If you left any of these params, the requrest won't work.