# Send POST data in input form and scrape page, Python, Requests library

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have problem. I dont know how i can send POST data and **scrape** content of next page.
Simple Example for better understanding:

Facebook website of profile recovery with one input: http://m.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover

Input:

```html
<input autocapitalize="off" class="y z ba" id="login_identify_search_placeholder" name="email" autofocus="1" placeholder="Adres e-mail lub numer telefonu" type="text">
```

I wanna make script, which recover my account, so i wanna send my email to input by POST and **scrape** next page. My code:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Soup = BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload={
"lsd": "AVqS_aom",
"email": "mycorrect email",
"did_submit": "Search"
}

session = requests.Session()
x = session.post('http://m.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover', headers=headers, data=payload)
#print x.content
x.encoding = "utf-8"
parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content)
print(parsed) #It's print me only started page, not next page with my finded profile. WTF??
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 0):

If the response is another page, I would recommend to use something like `BeautifulSoup`, to parse html and extract data from it, and also if you need history, you have it `x.history`, depends on which version of python you are using, you can use `BeautifulSoup` like:
python 3.x: `parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")`
python 2.x: `parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser")`

Comment: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable in line: parsed = BeautifulSoup(x.content, "html.parser")

Comment: you should first install BeautifulSoup using pip, `pip install bs4`, then in python `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: Man, i have installed BeautifulSoup and imported. Must add: from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup Soup = BeautifulSoup Now it's working, but print me only start page, not next page with send POST data.... Look at my code, it's updated

Comment: ok, I checked. first it's not that easy, you should first make a get request with that url, it would set some cookies in your session, then you should parse the page, and see how it would submit that form, a better way to see how it works is to use chrome's network tab in its inspector. after all it's easy but not that easy just with a one request to get it done.

Comment: I use Live http headers and i find this:

https://m.facebook.com/login/identify?lsd=AVqS_aom&email=email&did_submit=Search

But not working again :/ What is lsd=?

Comment: don't get confused, the form you submit has three inputs, just look at this:

Comment: `<form action="/login/identify/?ctx=recover" id="identify_yourself_flow" method="post">`**`<input autocomplete="off" name="lsd" type="hidden" value="AVpi6JYS"/>`**`<input autocapitalize="off" autofocus="1" class="x y z" id="login_identify_search_placeholder" name="email" placeholder="Email or phone" type="text"/><input class="bc bd be bf bg" id="did_submit" name="did_submit" type="submit" value="Search"/></form>`

Comment: just use find_all method from BeautifulSoup to find all inputs in the form.

Comment: I know about three inputs ( i update code, look at payload), but not working all time. Print me only start page, but i need next page, which display profile, when email is correct and scrap it.
What is lsd? You have different value than me

Comment: here "lsd" is a custom input name, another sites might use more names like this, it will be assigned when from the responses, so it would change with each request and you need to parse html to get the value of "lsd" because you should use it for the next request and this is the reason you won't get to the next page, remember you should get "lsd" from the exact session you wanna make the next request, either way it will fail.

Comment: also you are able to not parse response to get value of "lsd" here! just check responses the value of "lsd" would be somewhere in the response headers maybe.

Comment: check x.history to get it